# Shape weird in Cycles rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have made a condominium on blender, however the Cycles rendered image became something wrong. Eevee render is fine. Could you advise what is wrong with my Cycles setting?

Thanks,

First pic: Eevee rendered, Second pic: Cycles rendered.

[image: Eevee rendered]

[image: Cycles rendered]

Edit mode (Wireframe)
[image]

Edit mode (Solid)
[image]

Edit mode (Rendered in Cycles)
[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] in some more info? It's hard to tell what could be causing this from the given information.

Comment: Check for objects disabled for the viewport but enabled for render.

Comment: >HISEROD I have added the edit mode picture. thanks.

Comment: >susu Hi, I already checked about this rendering hidden objects. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Hello, I don't agree with the close vote, you have the same problem as this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212124/rendering-in-cycles-distorts-material Either you need to lower the scale in your displacement node, or set the displacement to "bump only" in the cycles settings

Comment: @Gorgious use the **Reopen** link at the bottom to nominate the question to be re-opened

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.  OP specifically said he already checked for duplicates.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for reopening again. I have not used the displacement node.

Comment: If you switch to CPU rendering does this go away?

Answer (score 0):

Check you displacement settings in shader editor for all of your materials .
I had similar problem, once i removed the displacement element from the shader , these weird rendering problems , disappeared .

[image]