# Rendering in cycles distorts material

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I now know that the problem I had with render mode was because I rendered in Cycles but I think I have to keep working with Cycles for this one so maybe someone can tell me, why the material looks like this.
In Eevee, the preview of the material is the same but it looks fine. Why does Cycles do something weird with it and how can I turn it off?
[image: Material.002]

Answer (score 1):

This was the problem!
In shading, the tutorial was about adding a lot of stuff and I guess something went wrong with "Displacement". I still don't know why this only happenend in cycles...

[image: Shading]

Comment: In cycles, displacement can be used as bump data which will look like it does in eevee, OR displacement which modifies the actual mesh at render time.

Comment: Thanks :) It‘s a long way for me to go...

Comment: You're getting there!

Comment: Fyi the default scale for displacement is high, a value around .02 will make more sense, probably.